# On the hyperboloid model, if the point $\mathbf{v}$ gets translated to the origin, then where does the point $\mathbf{x}$ go?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, rigid-transformation

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#Isometric_Transformations) has the answer in the case of the Poincaré disk model. When the point $\mathbf{v}$ is translated to the origin, then the point $\mathbf{x}$ is translated to

$$\frac{(1 + 2\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{x} + |\mathbf{x}|^2)\mathbf{v} + (1-|\mathbf{v}|^2)\mathbf{x}}{1 + 2\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{x} + |\mathbf{v}|^2|\mathbf{x}|^2}.$$

What is the equivalent for the [hyperboloid model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model)?

I've tried a variety of solutions and I haven't found any that are undeniably right. I've also looked for solutions and didn't find any that were concrete like the example given above.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? For example, are you able to write down the Lorentz transformation (i.e. the $3 \times 3$ matrix in $SO(2,1)$) which takes a vector $\mathbf{v}$ in the hyperboloid to a vector $\mathbf{x}$ in the hyperboloid?

Comment: @LeeMosher: I'm having difficulty even figuring out what $SO(2,1)$ **is**, and I only vaguely understand Lorentz transformations at best. The paucity of examples is being a real problem too. I learn best when given an example, the general case, and then another example.

Comment: I see that on the wikipedia page you linked for the hyperboloid model, they write it as $SO(1,2)$ instead of $SO(2,1)$. "Lorentz transformation" is just another word for a matrix which is an element of $SO(1,2)$.

Comment: The final paragraph of [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hyperboloid_model&oldid=977022650#Reflections_exchanging_two_specific_points) mentions a method to find a translation matrix from one point to another.

Answer (score 2):

First you need the Lorentz inner product 
$$\underbrace{( t_0, x_0, y_0)}_{\vec v^T}  \underbrace{\pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}}_J \underbrace{\pmatrix{t_1 \\ x_1 \\ y_1}}_{\vec w} = -t_0 t_1 + x_0 x_1 + x_2 y_2
$$
which I'll write in shorthand as
$$\vec v^T \, J \, \vec w
$$
The hyperboloid model $\mathbb{H}$ is simply the set of column vectors $\vec v$ that are solutions of the equation
$$\vec v^T \, J \, \vec v = -1, \, t_0 > 0
$$
in other words $\vec v^T = (t,x,y) \in \mathbb{H}$ if and only if $-t^2 + x^2 + y^2 = -1$.

Next you need Lorentz transformations, the $3 \times 3$ matrices $M$ having the property that
$$M^T J M = J
$$
These matrices form a group under matrix multiplication, that group is denoted $SO(1,2)$. Each of these matrices takes $\mathbb{H}$ to itself, and is an isometry of $\mathbb{H}$. This is the full isometry group of $\mathbb{H}$ in the hyperboloid model.

Once you have those things, your problem has an easy solution. Given the coordinates of column vectors $\vec v$, $\vec w \in \mathbb{H}$, you must solve for the unknown coordinates of a Lorentz transformation $M$ such that
$$M \vec v = \vec w
$$
Now your problem is just a big fat set of linear transformations to be solved, expressed in the unknown coordinates of $M$. You can get the final answer to your problem by setting $\vec w$ to be the zero vector.

Comment: I let $M = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}a&b&c \\ d&e&f \\ g&h&i \end{array} \right]$ and $\vec{v} = \left[ \begin{array}{c}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{array} \right]$ and got a system of nine *non-linear* equations. $$\begin{align*}a^2-d^2-g^2 &= 1 \\ b^2-e^2-h^2 &= 1 \\ c^2-f^2-i^2 &= 1 \\ ab-de-gh &= 0 \\ ac-df-gi &= 0 \\ bc-ef-hi &= 0 \\ ax_1+bx_2+cx_3 &= 1 \\ dx_1+ex_2+fx_3 &= 0 \\ gx_1+hx_2+ix_3 &= 0 \end{align*}$$ I'm sure this is solvable, but I'd like to be able to solve it without the help of a software package. I started doing some substitutions, but it quickly gets very messy.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman: Oh, yes, only the three from $M \vec v = \vec w$ are linear, sorry about that. But on the other hand there's lots of eliminations to do immediately, so yes, it's certainly solvable. For instance you can immediately eliminate $a,b,c$ using the first three.

Comment: That was the first thing I did: get $a=\sqrt{1+d^2+g^2}$ and likewise for the next two (which are actually equal to $-1$, not $1$). But then the next equations get messy fast. $ab-de-gh=0 \Rightarrow (1+d^2+g^2)(-1+e^2+h^2) = d^2e^2 + 2degh + g^2h^2$. I can make this a quadratic in $d$ to eliminate the fourth variable, but I still have five more variables to go and I already have a really messy equation here. Doing the same for the fifth equation allows me to eliminate $g$, I think. Still need to eliminate $e,f,h,i$. It's horrible.

Comment: I thought about it more, and I realized that if I can get the last three equations to have the same three variables each, then that immediately leads to the full solution. Which is slightly less daunting than substitutions all the way down. Thanks for your answer! It's really helped me actually tackle my problem. :)

Comment: After working on this for a couple hours, I challenge you to find a complete solution.

Comment: Had a key insight: $M\left[ \begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\end{array} \right] = -\vec{v}$ and I've very nearly got the solution. Just need to find a bug or two.

Comment: Finally solved it! I contest your claim that it is "an easy solution"! Took me several hours. But I did it! So, again, thank you very much for your input. Turned out to be just what I needed. :)

Comment: Glad to be of help.